# php перемещение загруженного файла

Tags: php

Есть файл upload.php, который может лежит в разных директориях сайта, на разных уровнях вложенности.

Этот скрипт загружает файл на сервер, который приходит от формы.

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], "" . $file_name);`

файлы загружаются в туже папку где лежит скрипт,  а нужно сделать что бы всегда загружались в папку uploads, который лежит в корне сайта. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $file_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// код в index.php
define('UPLOADS',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'. $file_name);
// код в "других файлах"
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], UPLOADS);
```

Comment: Сам догадаешься, в чем косяк?

Comment: dir наверное не подходит для перемещения файлов ))